# In ARC,dealloc is called but memory still increasing

Tags: ios, memory

In `viewController A` , I have a custom button, and click it will push to `viewController B`. And then I pop to A from B, the dealloc method in B is called to log something. Repeatly doing the push and pop actions again and again. Every pop action will release the `memory` but less the increase of the push action. So the `memory` is accumulatly increasing . I notice that from the `xcode7 debug navigator`. After 20 minus test, the `memory` increse from 30M to 118M, is it normal? Dealloc method is called means what? Is there a `memory` leak or exist abandoned `memory`?
  Thanks for every ideas.

Edit:
I upload a screenshot from instrument. Thanks for your tips. 
[image]

Comment: you can use `Profile` to check for leaked objects

Comment: Without seeing you code it's hard to tell. Instruments is always a good place to start, also try debugging on the device if you aren't as it tends to free up memory a lot more than the simulator from my experience. Are you registering for any notifications etc in viewControllerB? Or do you have a lot of NSLogs running?

Comment: @cezheng I have upload the result from profile..

Comment: @ElliottD'Alvarez  yeah... there exist notification,but I remove all notification in the proper place.. And there also exist a lot of NSLogs..But does it matter?

Comment: @seguedestination It will have some overhead but not massive amounts you are correct, not to account for this much. What might point you in the right direction is to click on 'Statistics' and change it to 'Call Trees'. Then on the right panel click the cog symbol, and select 'Invert Call Tree' and 'Hide System Libraries'. This should give you a list of functions which are retaining data. (In instruments)

Comment: @ElliottD'Alvarez After follow your suggestions, the instruments show me a lot of functions. You mean the function have retaining data that cause leaks?What do the data cause, is it a bad thing of the functions in that list?

Comment: @ElliottD'Alvarez oh..I know, when I click the leaks row and select the call tree, I can see the functions of my code are listing. And the list has a column "leaks". I think this really mean there exist a leak

Comment: @seguedestination It generally means the things that are holding the data. So for example you may see things like persistantStoreCoordinator which tend to highlight things being held by CoreData, so you can see if it's the CoreData functions holding reference to data etc. It's not bad to have a full list, I was just thinking this could highlight some of the functions which are holding data and may give you clues as to what is. What is showing up in the leaks column, or what are the main function listed (anything with a high number in the bytes used column)